# Unable to connect to google api client

Tags: android, google-play-services

I just installed my app from Play Store and it can not connect to the Google API Client and it is not giving me any error message. Also the sign in button is not working.
Everything was working fine when it was in debug mode.
If you can help me or forward me somewhere please help me.

Comment: check the `SHA` for release app, it may be different if you're using special keystore file for generating signed apk.

Comment: WOW! You are absolutely right and you have no idea how much you have helped me. Thank you Thank you Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

When you're debugging the app `SHA` hash is different and when you generate signed apk and chooses `keystore.jks` file, then `SHA` is changed.

So you have to add new `SHA` in Google API.

To avoid this, you can set same `keystore.jks` for both debug and release app.

To do so in AndroidStudio create signing configuration

[image: Signing Config]

And set same configuration for both debug and release build types

[image: Set to debug and release config]

Hope, it'll help you.